# Using of the same GPU memeoy object

Tags: opencl

Suppose you create two threads and making both of them entering a loop there both of them start the same kernel which uses same opencl memory object (Buffer in cl.hpp in my case). Will it work properly? Do opencl allow to run in the same time different kernels with the same memory object?

(I am using opencl C++ wrapper cl.hpp and beignet Intel open source library.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both threads are using the same in-order command queue, it will work just fine; it just becomes a race as to which thread enqueues their work first. From the OpenCL runtime point of view, it's just commands in a queue.

OpenCL 1.1 (and newer) is threadsafe except for clSetKernelArg and clEnqueueNDRangeKernel for a given kernel; you'll need to lock around that.

If however your threads are using two different command queues then you shouldn't be using the same memory object without then using OpenCL Event objects to synchronize. Unless it is read-only; that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Read operation on same OpenCL memory objects, by concurrent kernels, wouldn't cause any functionality issue. In case of write operation, it sure will cause functionality issues.

What is the objective of running multiple kernels concurrently? Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287851/opencl-multiple-command-queue-for-concurrent-ndkernal-launch) to similar question.