# OpenCL FPGA: Kernel Execution of 2 copies of same kernel is not being made in parallel. In addition to that, there is also idle time in between them

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, fpga, intel-fpga, opencl-c

My goal is to complete FFTs of 2 - 4K Data points together. Hence, I made 2 kernel objects from the same kernel and Enqueued the tasks at once, i.e. without any Buffer Read-Write or any callbacks in between. I find out that it doesn't happen that way. In addition to that, there is also some idle time between the executions. Can someone please  explain?
[image: AOCL Report of the Program]

I was expecting both of them to run in parallel because my FPGA seems to have more area. About 38 percent of it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question that kind off answers my doubts. It can be found[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287851/opencl-multiple-command-queue-for-concurrent-ndkernal-launch)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCL queue works sequentially, so one kernel is executed after the other. This makes sure that - if kernel 2 reads memory that kernel 1 has updated, there is no race condition like if they would run concurrently. There may also be some latency to start execution of a kernel.

To run multiple kernels in parallel, you can try multiple queues.

Comment: I have used 2 different command queues, different kernel objects for both and there is no common buffer or memory shared between them too. I have also checked the report on Device area utilization and I still have approx 70 percent of resources not assigned to anything..